# retrieving a part of current year in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

i want to retrieve the last two digits of current year for ex- i want to retrieve "13" from current year "2013'. help me provide a suitable query for this

Thanx

Answer (score 9):

try this one

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datefield, '%y')
```

Answer (score 4):

use `DATE_FORMAT`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%y')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/7491)
- [MySQL DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 0):

Combine the [Extract function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract), and the [Substring function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) like:

```
SELECT Substring(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2013-07-02'), 3)
```

would return: `13`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use date_format function with :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%y')
```